# what is this error message complaining about? and how to resolve it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

try to apply a patch and compile received warning message:

```
<some_file>: In function '-[XXXXX saveAndCreate:]':
<some_file>:262: warning: 'NSString' may not respond to '-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:'
<some_file>:262: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
<some_file>:262: warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept
<some_file>:262: warning: '...' as arguments.)
distcc[6493] ERROR: compile (null) on localhost failed
```

which is complaining about this code,

```
[clientHost findAvailableIn:
    [clientHost defaultVMPath]
    baseName:
        [displayName stringByAppendingPathExtension:PL_BUNDLE_EXTENSION]
    nameFormat:[[displayName
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%"
                                               withString:@"%%"]
                     stringByAppendingString:@" %u.xxxx"]
    startIndex:2
    contextInfo:contextInfo];
```

and here is part of the compile command:

```
lin32/gcc-5363-1/bin/i686-apple-darwin8-gcc -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -march=pentium-m -mtune=prescott -Werror -Wall -Wno-trigraphs -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -pipe -O2 -g3 -gfull -Wno-pointer-sign -x objective-c -fobjc-exceptions -fpascal-strings -fmessage-length=0
```

googled the warning and tried the method [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=654710) , but still got warning message alike.

i am ignorant in Mac development, spare me if this is something obvious (and i donnot know if the information provide above is surfficent, let me know what else needed to provide). thanx.

**edit**:
1) extend the code block.
2) correct the warning message.

Comment: i extended the code block, so that it might be more clear what is the immutable receiver in your answer.

Comment: could you isolate the problem better by creating new variables and try and format the code to be readable in SO?

Comment: ok, i will come back tmr morning, (my time). maybe my colleague should have the answer by then, thanx for the help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is referencing a different line the one you cited. The message you use is called `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` which is fine on `NSString`. However the method `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString` attempts to change the receiver. `NSString` is immutable and can therefore not be changed. If you want to use that method send it to a `NSMutableString` object.

Comment: You are not using `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString` in the code you posted. So I can't really help.

Comment: really sorry about the confusion. the warning message are the same.

Comment: where do you create displayName

Comment: you are rite, the displayName is immutable, create a NSMutableString solved the problem (with replaceOccurrencesOfString). thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`? What is very surprising is that you would receive this warning, but no warning on `-stringByAppendingPathExtension`. Is this really the only warning you're receiving?

I recommend breaking up the code to create some temporary variables. You're doing so many nested method calls, it makes it very hard to be certain where your errors are. The compiler will optimize out most temporary variables, so there's no reason to avoid them when it makes the code clearer.

Comment: yes, that is the only warning message i got. i will let my colleague do it. almost their time now. thanx.